# Should I develop a console application along the WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application

I built a rather simple application in C#/WPF that finds, copies txt files in separate folders which represent each month, and then packs them into one large txt file but inside each month folder for each month.

There are lot of files like 10000 and the txt file for each month can reach like 1.5GB, so it needs like 25 minutes to finish.

The two steps are separated, copying into appropriate month folder and then the second step is packing a txt file for each month.

I want to be able to automate these steps along other heavy duty tasks like running Access 2000 macros that check data integrity(also 20 mins to finish), running TSQL stored procedures in a sequence(20 mins to finsih). I started doing this in Powershell script.

I can build another console application that holds the steps of copying and packing and run those by will, but should it be separate application?
Can I use WPF app as a console application as well? 
Or build a library application and use it in separate WPF and Console app?

Comment: I'd put all the shared logic in an assembly that's used by both a WPF application and a console application.

Comment: I would definitely do what @EdPlunkett suggests and separate these into separate assemblies.  Since it can take such a long time to run, you could go further and slap some kind of external interface, such as gRPC on the headless implementation and have the UI connect to that to get status.

Comment: Maybe this should do the work in a windows service. Reading from an input message queue that passes it tasks to do. Outputting the results to another message queue. Then the WPF front end could be used to add to the tasks and report the results.

Comment: There are also various cron - like apps people have written for windows or just windows task sheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a WPF application also as a pure console application.

You could do it like this: When you call the EXE from the command line, then add a parameter, e.g. `/c` for "console", or similar. Then, in the `main` function of your application, look for that parameter, and when it is set, then continue as a console application and don't create any windows.

Comment: Yes its plausible. But need to set a mechanism for each console parameter. By the way, what do i add to command line arguments in Debug tab in project properties? It doesn't compile without setting some letters in command line arguments for the project.